# Reading lines of .txt file with Javascript (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

**I am new to competitive programming in JavaScript** and I'd like to know **how I can feed an input text in a function** and **how to work with it** (and if possible knowing the latest syntaxfor doing so)
Here is my input.txt =>

```
5
37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250
46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538
74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629
91942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250
23067588207539346171171980310421047513778063246676
```

Here is my **Javascript(Node.js)** boilerplate code :

```js
process.stdin.resume();         // I supose this reads the file it's beeing passed .txt => .js
process.stdin.setEncoding("ascii"); 
_input = "";
process.stdin.on("data", function (input) {
    _input += input;            // this adds up each character/line(?) it reads to the _input variable
});

process.stdin.on("end", function () {
   processData(_input);         // And finally sends the input multiple times(?) (I guess)
});

function processData(input) {
    console.log(input)          // Because the input will only log the first line of the input.txt file (5)

    // I'd like to:
      // 1) Be able to perform my algorithm using line by line input
      // 2) Be able to gather multiple lines (of my choice) before performing my argorithm, 
         // let's say store multiple lines of input in an array like arr = ['line1', 'line2', 'line3'...]
}
```

Thanks for helping me understand.
source: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler013/problem

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the input is a string seperated with "\n" and console.log() breaks on each line, meaning it will only show the first line.

```js
process.stdin.resume();         
process.stdin.setEncoding("ascii"); 
_input = "";
process.stdin.on("data", function (input) {
    _input += input;            
});

process.stdin.on("end", function () {
   processData(_input);         
});

function processData(input) {

    console.log(input)        // => 5

    input = input.split("\n");

    console.log(input)        // will show the input (array) =>   [ '5',
//                            '37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250',
//                            '46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538',
//                            '74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629',
//                            '91942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250',
//                            '23067588207539346171171980310421047513778063246676' ]

}
```